# REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't translate back references

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple code :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('test_4444','test_([0-9]+)','ok\1');
```

It is supposed to result in `ok4444` but the result is `ok1`

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Just need a double back slash :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('test_4444','test_([0-9]+)','ok\\1');
```